# Google Script to remove duplicates exceeds processing time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that has 10k+ rows of data.  While it should be rare, there could be instances of duplicate data being entered into the tab, and I have written a script to search for and remove those duplicates.  For a while, this script has been running nicely and doing exactly what I expected it to do.  But now that the tab has grown to over 10k rows, the script is exceeding the 6 minute time limit.

I've based this function on [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates).

```
// remove duplicates on Ship Details Complete
function duplicateShipDetailsComplete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Shipment Details Complete");
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 16)
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  var keepData = new Array();
  var deleteCount = 0;

  for(i in sourceData) {  // look for duplicates
    var row = sourceData[i];
    var duplicate = false;  // initialize as not a duplicate
    for(j in keepData) {  // compare the current row in data to the rows in newData
      if(row[2] == keepData[j][2]  // duplicate Partner Invoice?
        && row[4] == keepData[j][4]  // duplicate vPO?
        && row[5] == keepData[j][5]  // duplicate SKU?
        && row[7] == keepData[j][7]) {  // duplicate qty?
        duplicate = true;  // only if ALL criteria are duplicate, set row as a duplicate
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate) {  // If the row is NOT a duplicate
      keepData.push(row);  // add to newData
    } else {
      deleteCount++;  // keep track of duplicates being deleted
    }
  }

  sourceRange.clear();
  sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, keepData.length, keepData[0].length).setValues(keepData);  // paste the keepData into the Working sheet
  return deleteCount;
}
```

I've thought about breaking it up into pieces; process 1/3 of the data in each of 3 different calls.  But this is actually being called from a different function that emails the returned deleteCount value, if it's greater than 0.

```
// Nightly email after checking for duplicates in Ship Details Complete
function sendEmailShipDetails() {
  var deleted = duplicateShipDetailsComplete();
  var update = parseFloat(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dept/Class").getRange(1,6).getValue()).toFixed(2);

  if(deleted > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      "me@myoffice.com",
      "Shipment Details Cleaned Up",
      deleted + " Shipment Detail line(s) were deleted from Complete as duplicates.\n" + 
      "Updated Value: " + update + "\n"
    );       
  }
}
```

Even without that email function, it's exceeding the limit when I call duplicateShipDetailsComplete() directly.  I suppose I could write three different functions (first 1/3, second 1/3, third 1/3) and update a cell somewhere with the results for each, and then call the email function separately to get that value.  I'd feel a little better about that if I could write 1 function and pass parameters to it, but this is all coming from a Time Based Trigger, and you can't pass parms from those.  But before I started to do that, I thought I'd check to see if someone had other suggestions on how I could make the existing code more efficient.  Or, see if someone had totally different ideas on how I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Finding duplicates is most efficient when the data is sorted. Can you sort your data by the columns being compared? 2) Does Google Apps seriously not have a "find" function of some sort? you really have to program the whole search in javascript?

Comment: Create  a sidebar and call the spreadsheet API directly from the client instead of from the server. This way you're not bound by server-side script time limits.